# How do i write this query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flash-message

I have an existing sqlalchemy objects which i generated into sql (postgres)

```
class Category(Model, BaseNestedSets):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(400), index=True, unique=False)
    image = Column(ImageColumn(thumbnail_size=(30, 30, True), size=(300, 300, True)))
    products = relationship("Catalog", backref='categs')
    # TODO do a multi-joins and filter in order to fetch sizes and colors from categories.

    @classmethod
    def get_parents_list(cls, db, category_id):
        beginning_getter = db.session.query(cls).filter(cls.id == category_id).cte(name='parent_for', recursive=True)
        with_recursive = beginning_getter.union_all(db.session.query(cls).filter(cls.id == beginning_getter.c.parent_id))
        return db.session.query(with_recursive)
```

With this, i have the following SQL query:
*Additional modifications to the query are enclosed by asterisk*

How do i implement the new sqlalchemy object? what should I add?

```
WITH RECURSIVE children_for (rgt,
    lft,
    id,
    name,
    image,
    parent_id,
    LEVEL,
    tree_id)
AS (
    SELECT
        category.rgt AS rgt,
        category.lft AS lft,
        category.id AS id,
        category.name AS name,
        category.image AS image,
        category.parent_id AS parent_id,
        category.level AS LEVEL,
        category.tree_id AS tree_id
    FROM
        category
    WHERE
        category.id = 122
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        category.rgt AS category_rgt,
        category.lft AS category_lft,
        category.id AS category_id,
        category.name AS category_name,
        category.image AS category_image,
        category.parent_id AS category_parent_id,
        category.level AS category_level,
        category.tree_id AS category_tree_id
    FROM
        category,
        children_for
    WHERE
        category.parent_id = children_for.id
)
SELECT *DISTINCT*
    children_for.rgt AS children_for_rgt, children_for.lft AS children_for_lft, children_for.id AS children_for_id, children_for.name AS children_for_name, children_for.image AS children_for_image, children_for.parent_id AS children_for_parent_id, children_for.level AS children_for_level, children_for.tree_id AS children_for_tree_id
FROM
    children_for  *JOIN catalog cat ON children_for.id = cat.category_id*
```

Comment: [`Query.distinct()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.distinct) and [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join). Could you please expand what you mean by "I need to display a single column instead of ...", because your example SQL does not quite match that.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I feel what you mentionned above is what should be used but where does it fit in? i will reedit the question to omit that part. i would rather print out all the table columns